# Are all ordinal attribute types nominal?

Tags: terminology, ordinal-data, categorical-data

I'm currently writing a .NET library to handle various statistical/classification tasks and I am currently writing the structures to represent nominal and ordinal data.

In doing so, I've been debating whether or not the structures that handle ordinal data should derive from the structures that handle nominal data.

My thought is that yes, all ordinal data *is* nominal data; even though it means huge (or infinite) sets, each of them is an attribute that while being able to compared to another attribute for rank (for lack of a better term, which implies ordinal) can still be compared to for equality and is still a label (nominal).

Comment: I know this is old but going to leave a comment anyway in case future people see this. #1: Don't write this code. Someone else who has researched the area more has already written it so you should import their stuff instead. #2: Yep, the data-structure you are considering is correct. You could look at [Ord](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html) for a nice well-thought-out tree of the standard ⊂ for statistical data types.

Comment: @isomorphismes If someone else has written this code for .NET would you point it out?  Ord looks nice, but it's for Haskell, and the question clearly indicates this is for .NET.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely make the distinction between *discrete* ordinal variables and *continuous* ordinal variables. For the second case, in practice there never is any sense in comparing values for equality.

I don't see a sound reason to state that continuous ordinal variables are in fact nominal: what would be the gain?

Comment: The design of the object oriented program would be nicer.

Comment: Well, not if it doesn't reflect reality. You're going to get stuck somewhere down the line...

Comment: @xmjx hit the mark with the intent and the gain; Nominal dervies from Ordinal.  Discrete ordinals and continuous ordinals can be derivations of Discrete ordinals when I get to that point.  Another example, Nominal types can do two things, say if they are equal to another nominal type, and tell if they are missing; these characteristics/methods are shared with all ordinal ordinal values.

Comment: How could you have a continuous ordinal variable?